# Angular template html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make fourteen html pages with this template, I would only change the items that are with comments. How can I achieve this with Angular? Can I do it with ng-repeat or another directive?

```html
<div class="container">
    <hr>
    <ol class="breadcrumb small">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a ui-sref="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a >Seguro para Personas</a></li>
        <!-- Include ruta Breadcrumb -->
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Auto</li>
    </ol>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <!-- Include Image and alt -->
            <img src="images/sp_auto.png" width="100%" alt="Seguro Auto">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">

            <!-- Include Icon -->
            <h1><span><img src="images/icon_auto.svg" alt=""></span> Auto</h1>

            <!-- Include Destacado -->
            <p class="h4 text-secondary my-4">Sabemos la importancia de asegurar tu vehículo hoy por todos los accidentes que ocurren a diario, nosotros te ayudamos a proteger a tu familia y a tu vehículo.</p>

            <!-- Include Description -->
            <p>Te ofrecemos una amplia gama de beneficios, coberturas y servicios, desde coberturas básicas de accidentes hasta coberturas completas frente a choques. Robos, daños a terceros, accidentes de personas y asistencias vehiculares como servicios de grúa y chofer de reemplazo.</p>

            
            <div ng-include='"views/btQuieroInfo.html"'></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div ng-include='"views/masSeguros.html"'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowin more details, it could be simple as:

```
<!-- Include Image and alt -->
<img ng-src="{{seguroImage}}" width="100%" alt="Seguro Auto">
```

And in your controller you'll have to define the {{seguroImage}} actual value.
Same for the other variables

Comment: True, but suppose I want to change the styles of some element, would I have to change them on each page?

Comment: Not sure if what you want, but styles can also be variables which come from your controller: <div class="{{autoStyle100}}">

Comment: It is advised to use ng-src over src while dynamically populating an image